# loop jumps from firs if to the second with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, css, switch-statement, hammer.js

I want to use hammer.js pinchout option to switch images (make them larger and fade them).
I've put the images in the background of some divs and I change the css background property to make them larger and disappear. Animating all with webkit.

So far this all works. But I've tried to make a simple switch loop to change the divs one after the other. I first with if and if else and a var to act as switch and later on with the switch option.
The problem is that the the iPad ignores the brakes or pauses and just run the code repentantly from some reason. When I run the code and try to pinchout 2 images change one after the other and the alert given is x-3 (meaning the script did not stop after the first case in the switch and continue to the 3rd before even executing the second!.

please help...

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = 1; // position
var y = 1; // switch
var z = 90; // z-index of layer
var a = 2; // image number (start from image 3 as the first 3 are already set)

window.onload = function() {

    Hammer(document.body).on("pinchout", function() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');

        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:
            box1.style.opacity = "0";
            box1.style.backgroundSize = "200% 200%";
            x=x+1;
            a++;
            z--;
            break;

            case 2:
        box2.style.opacity = "0";
        box2.style.backgroundSize = "200% 200%";
        //box1.style.backgroundImage='url("' + a +'.jpg)"';
        box1.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
        box1.style.zIndex= z;
        x++;
        a++;
        z--;
        alert(x);
        break;

            case 3:
        box1.style.opacity = "1";
        box2.style.zIndex= z;
        box3.style.opacity = "0"
        box3.style.backgroundSize = "200% 200%";
        x++;
        a++;
        z--;
        break;

        }


});}



    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok,
got it. the pinchout event  is not fire only once.
so you need to add something to check when it ends and then run your code.
like this:

```
var isListening = false;
var instance = Hammer(document.body);
instance.on('pinch', function(e) {
  if (isListening) return;
  instance.on('release', onPinchEnd);
});

function onPinchEnd(e) {
  instance.off('release', onPinchEnd);
  alert("here"); // do stuff on pinch end.
}
```